# Trouble excluding matched values in SQL

Tags: sql, sequelpro

I am trying to bring up potential name matches with keywords and then transfer the IDs from one table to the other. My issue is arising where I cannot filter out results from the ID table that have already been matched (and therefore have a matching ID in the initial table). I have tried this:

```
SELECT m.sname, u.fname, u.UUID, m.UUID
FROM pl_MDR m
LEFT JOIN pl_UUID u     ON m.UUID=u.UUID
WHERE m.UUID is null
      AND m.sname LIKE "%chic%"
      AND u.fname LIKE "%chic%";
```

As well as attempting to mimic a full outer join:

```
SELECT m.sname, u.fname, u.city, u.UUID, m.UUID
FROM pl_UUID u
LEFT JOIN pl_MDR m     ON u.UUID != m.UUID
WHERE m.UUID is null
      AND m.sname LIKE "%chic%"
      AND u.fname LIKE "%chic%"
UNION ALL
SELECT m.sname, u.fname, u.city, u.UUID, m.UUID
FROM pl_UUID u
RIGHT JOIN pl_MDR m     ON u.UUID != m.UUID
WHERE m.UUID is null
      AND m.sname LIKE "%chic%"
      AND u.fname LIKE "%chic%"
```

NOTE: `"%chic%"` is just any keyword/string

Comment: If you want more people to help with your issue, it would be better if you included test data depicting the issue and not just your query.

Comment: I am assuming you have tried the full outer join and not just trying to mimic it?

Comment: full outer join isnt supported in sequel pro. only produces errors